# I have problem with wget module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, wget

can anyone solve my code pls? Im too begginer
Also, I would be very happy if you tell me how I can do it more efficiently without having to create a different function for each file type.

(You can think of this code as a terminal for a research facility that existed in the 1990s when the internet wasn't good, so I want to slow down the download speed and make it feel like it's really 90's.)

```
import wget

x = ""

def png_download():
    print("this code is can only download png btw")
    time.sleep(1)
    
    print("enter url")
    command = input('Terminal: ').strip()
    command = x
    
    
    # file url
    remote_url = ("'"+x+"'")
    
    # 
    local_file = 'file.png'
    
    # aksiyon
    wget.download(remote_url, local_file)

while True: #Terminal
    print ("")
    command = input('Terminal: ').strip()
    if command == 'Download_png':
        png_download()
        
    else:
        print("")
```

If I run the code and enter the url this happens:

````
  File "c:\Dosyalar\Yazılım\Python\Foundation Terminal 14\Terminal Downloader Extension ENG .py", line 28, in <module>
    png_download()
  File "c:\Dosyalar\Yazılım\Python\Foundation Terminal 14\Terminal Downloader Extension ENG .py", line 22, in png_download
    wget.download(remote_url, local_file)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\wget.py", line 526, in download
    (tmpfile, headers) = ulib.urlretrieve(binurl, tmpfile, callback)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 239, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 501, in open
    req = Request(fullurl, data)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 320, in __init__
    self.full_url = url
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 346, in full_url
    self._parse()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 375, in _parse
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
ValueError: unknown url type: '%27%27' ```
````

Comment: When you enter the URL  did you put `http://` at the start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ValueError: unknown url type: '%27%27' ```

`27` is (hex) code for `'` character, meaning that first argument you provided for `wget.download` is just `''`, which clearly is not legal address. This is due to fact that you set x to empty string (`x = ""`) and nowhere changed it, then did

```
remote_url = ("'"+x+"'")
```

and

```
wget.download(remote_url, local_file)
```

Assuming that user always gives legal URL, then your `png_download` should be altered to

```
def png_download():
    print("this code is can only download png btw")
    time.sleep(1)
    
    print("enter url")
    remote_url = input('Terminal: ').strip()
    # 
    local_file = 'file.png'
    
    # aksiyon
    wget.download(remote_url, local_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a much easier way to download files with Python:

```py
import os
import requests

def download_file_to(file_url, destination_folder, new_file_name=None):
    if new_file_name:
        file_name = new_file_name
    else:
        file_name = file_url.split("/")[-1]
    r = requests.get(file_url)
    file_path = os.path.join(destination_folder, file_name)
    with open(file_path, "wb") as code:
        code.write(r.content)
```

This method will download any file from the web (using the `requests` library) into the folder you specified, and you can rename the file if you'd like.

Comment: Why is that 'much easier'?

Comment: The ``requests`` library is more standard for this type of action.